# Distribution of marginal Wiener process.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $(W^1,W^2)$ be a two-dimensional Wiener process with correlation $\rho$. Let $\mathcal{F}^1_t$ be the filtration generated by $W^1$ up to $t$.

I would intuitively think that for $h$ measurable and integrable we have
$$
E[h(W^2_T) \lvert \mathcal{F}^1_T]  = E[h(W^2_T) \lvert W^1_T] ,
$$
since $W^1_T$ contains all the information in the path. I am though unable to prove it. Is it true and how do I go about showing it?

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that there exists some Brownian motion $W^3$ independent of $W^1$ such that $W^2=\rho W^1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}W^3$.

Comment: @Did thanks! I knew that, but I unfortunately can still not see it. Do you mind supplying an additional hint?

Comment: By the principle of "integrating what is independent and taking out what is measurable" in conditional expectations, one has $$E(h(W^2_T)\mid\mathcal F^1_T)=E(h(\rho W^1_T+\sigma W^3_T)\mid\mathcal F^1_T)=g(W^1_T)$$ with $\sigma^2=1-\rho^2$ and $$g(w)=E(h(\rho w+\sigma W^3_T))$$ and $$E(h(W^2_T)\mid W^1_T)=E(E(h(W^2_T)\mid\mathcal F^1_T)\mid W^1_T)=E(g(W^1_T)\mid W^1_T)=g(W^1_T)$$ hence you are done.

Comment: @Did Thanks once again! I would, of course, accept this is an answer, but I assume you do not really care about getting credit.

Comment: Good conjecture... Instead you might write down an answer yourself, in your own words, if only to check that every step works.